# Save FolderPicker location for next time in windows 10 universal apps c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal, fileopenpicker

I am getting file by using FolderPicker from device, by using this below code.

```
FolderPicker pk = new FolderPicker();

        pk.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
        pk.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        pk.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        var folder = await pk.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        var files =await folder.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (var files in files)
        {

        }
```

For each time i have to pick the folder location, for that reason i want to save the folder location first time, when i open app next time get the file from that path, any one please help me to achieve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer in MSDN forms https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b5a23a11-f526-4a59-bcca-af6a563589d9/save-folderpicker-location-for-next-time-in-windows-10-universal-apps-c?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FolderPicker.SettingsIdentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.settingsidentifier.aspx) for that. If you set the value to something like "My Downloads" then the next time you use the picker, it will start in the location you picked previously.

Comment: I used SettingsIdentifier but it's asking for second time, i want to get files from first time picked location automatically.